# assign a list to a local variable in scheme

Tags: recursion, scheme

I'm trying to find a way to assign a list to a local variable, and then add that list to a symbol to make a new list, an improper list. Example below is to illustrate this:

Input: `'?e1 ((?e1 ?e0) (?e1 ?ex) (?e1 ?ey) (?e1 ?e2))`

Expected output: `(?e1 (?e0 ?ex ?ey ?e2))`

The idea is that compare (car graph) in all nested list with ?e1, add them together to form a list, assign the list to a variable, finally (list '?e1 (new list))

But actually the recursion make my code fail .....

I have try to write a program, but the output from this is quite ridiculous:

```
(define agrv '((?e1 ?e0) (?e1 ?ex) (?e1 ?ey) (?e1 ?e2)))

(define successor
  (lambda (node graph)    
    (if (equal? node (car graph))
        (cdr graph)
        '())))

(define (find-dst node graph)  
  (if (null? graph)
      '()
      (let ((custom-list (append (list (successor node (car graph))) (find-dst node (cdr graph)))))
        (list node custom-list))))

(find-dst '?e1 agrv)
```

output is: `'(?e1 ((?e0) ?e1 ((?ex) ?e1 ((?ey) ?e1 ((?e2))))))`

Can someone please explain where I get wrong??? Thank you very much!!

Comment: one of your problems is that cdr gives you a list, not an item...

Comment: of course it should return a list, cos im using recursion here, but the new list is the list of the rest elements in the previous list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to get more acquainted with the fundamental Scheme procedures, since your procedure could simply be expressed as follows:

```
(define (find-dst node graph)
  (cons node
        (list
         (map cadr
              (filter (lambda (e) (eq? node (car e))) graph)))))
```

I would rewrite your example as follows:

```
(define (find-dst node graph)

  (define (sub graph)
    (if (null? graph)
        null
        (let ((e (car graph)))
          (if (eq? node (car e))
              (cons (cadr e) (sub (cdr graph)))
              (sub (cdr graph))))))

  (cons node (list (sub graph))))

(find-dst '?e1 '((?e1 ?e0) (?e1 ?ex) (?e1 ?ey) (?e1 ?e2)))
=> '(?e1 (?e0 ?ex ?ey ?e2))
```

**EDIT**

Regarding the additional question in your comment, if I understood it correctly, you could do something which is close:

```
(define (find-dst2 node graph)
  (let ((r (find-dst node graph)))
    (cons node
          (map (lambda (e) (find-dst e graph)) (cadr r)))))

(find-dst2 '?e1 '((?e1 ?e0) (?e0 ?ex) (?e0 ?ey) (?e1 ?e2)))

=> '(?e1 (?e0 (?ex ?ey)) (?e2 ()))
```

Comment: just one more question, if i have an input like this `'((?e1 ?e0) (?e0 ?ex) (?e0 ?ey) (?e1 ?e2))` is there anyway to make an ouput to be: `'((?e1 (?e0 (?ex ?ey)) ?e2))` ?????

Comment: If graph equal to `'((?e1 ?e0) (?e0 ?ex) (?e0 ?ey) (?e1 ?e2))`, or is sub equal to '(?e1 ?e0) and graph equal to '((?e0 ?ex) (?e0 ?ey) (?e1 ?e2)) in this case?

Comment: graph is equal to '((?e1 ?e0) (?e0 ?ex) (?e0 ?ey) (?e1 ?e2)) in this case :)